# orderByChild"timestamp" not working firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have been all over the internet for a while now check what am doing what am doin wrong but I haven't found a solution to my problem , am trying to `orderByChild("timestamp")` but the layout remains static even after reversing the layouts which is quite frustrating.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: How is `MchatDatabase` defined? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo mchatdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getinstance().gerReference().child("Chat").child(currentUserId)

Comment: @AlexMamo currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getuid();     the items are being populated but they don't change position as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by "they don't change position as expected"?

Comment: @AlexMamo I Just wanted newest to appear on top but the items remain static

Comment: Have you started listening for changes?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes I did but nothing is happening still , what might be the issue, Is it still possible to order items on the layouts using timestamp?